# как избежать вложенные формы

Tags: php, laravel

Друья! Есть форма. Визуально выглядит так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По кнопке "добавить" добавляется запись из инпута `tag` в БД и делается выборка по ним и заполняется в `foreach`. По клику на запись она должна удалиться из БД. Передаю постом поле `del` (тут хранится id записи). Удаление происходит, но удаляет последнюю запись. Как мне правильно передать id записи в мой скрипт?

```
<form role="form" method="post"><div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_POST['id'];  ?>">
    <input type="text" name="tag">
    <?php  
        $users = DB::table('searchtag')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
        foreach ($users as $item) {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='del' value='".$item->id."'>";
            echo '<input name="delite" type="submit" value="'.$item->tag.'   Х" class="btn bg-olive btn-flat margin">';
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="tagbutton" value="Добавить" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Comment: Показать скрипт? Неееее, это же секретная разработка.

Comment: 1) Во view использовать конект к базе это сильно перенесите хотя бы в контроллер. 
2) Это все делайте аяксом при клике аякс запрос на сервер с ид тега для удаления.